# Can we use MS access db with flutter webpage (form)?

Tags: flutter-web

1. How to use MS Access Database for the Flutter Webpage(form)?
2. How to perform CRUD Operations by Flutter webpage in MS Access
   Database? Basic operations like read and write database in MS Access
   through flutter webpage.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, no.
However flutter can read or write to excel files with csv extension
Thanks